# Jpeg To WebP encoding in Skiasharp produce grayscale result on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webp

Xamarin.Forms latest release. Tested on few phones.

This code works fine on IOS and Android-Emulator, but on android hardware phones produce grayscale images

```
                    var d = SKBitmap.Decode(stream).Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Webp, 65);

                    using (var outFile = new FileInfo(dest).Create())
                    {
                        d.SaveTo(outFile);
                    }
```

Problem in Encode() and webp format, tried other formats, works fine

Comment: I would suggest logging a bug - https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues

Comment: yeah, tested on older version of skiasharp and it works

Comment: Posted bug a year ago, zero response and still not fixed https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/1535

Answer (score 0):

bug in skiasharp 2.80.2, works in 1.68.3